# jQuery and NiceScroll 3.6.0

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

I'm using `NiceScroll 3.6.0` [link](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll), and some reason it's not working with `jQuery 2.1.3`. I have a site ( 89.135.115.70/basicWebPage/ ), with this configuration, and if I initalize the NiceScroll it's stop working, and i don't know scroll on page.
Please help me.

Comment: Please be specific: what does it do? Can you reproduce it? Can you provide a jsFiddle to show it?

Comment: your HTML document is not valid. Validate and fix! NiceScroll works with the version of jQuery you are running, working demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/ogmeuyw3/.